# How to extend __git_ps1? I get "command not found"

Tags: linux, git, bash

`__git_ps1` returns `(unknown)` instead of nothing when I am not in a git directory. That's a change I'm not too happy with. So I am trying to extend it to get the old behaviour back. So, I added this in my `~/.bashrc` and made sure that `/etc/bash_completion` is sourced before it:

```
__git_silent_ps1() {
    local b='$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")'
    if ["$b" != " ((unknown))"]; then
        echo -n $b
    fi
}
```

But when I use `__git_silent_ps1` in my prompt definition, I get:

```
-bash: [$(__git_ps1 " (%s)"): command not found
```

When I just use `__git_ps1` in my prompt definition I don't get that error but it displays the branch. Any idea why I am getting the error and how I can fix it?

Comment: That's... odd. My versions of `__git_ps1` have never done that. Do you have a very old version? Or possibly a stray incomplete .git directory ?

Comment: No. But it may be an issue with git and my home directory layout (which has some global settings in ~/.git)

Comment: Well there's your problem. Git sees that, knows it appears to be within a repository, and tries and fails to figure out what branch is checked out. You might want to rename it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as one doesn't write `rmsomefile.txt`, one shouldn't write `["$b"`.

```
    if [ "$b" != " ((unknown))" ]; then
```

Comment: Thanks. I was sure it was the `__git_ps1` call.